# ASMX page returning old Web Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I must be dumb (and I'm sure I am making mistake but can't figure out at the moment).

I deployed ASMX page containing reference to a Class Library which contains few web methods. It exposes those methods when I browse the site. But some how it is not showing me any further methods which I have added in it. The DLL is strong name assembly.

I tried re-adding the reference but there is no difference.

### Update

It worked but I don't know whether the files are not updated or references, so what I did, I removed the referenced, deleted the files from bin and GAC and then re-added the files. After rebuilding, I deployed them again and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the web reference that you added to your project.  If the class library contains the web reference, update the reference in it and then re-add/update your project's reference to the class library.  If you don't update, then the only stubs/methods that your project will know about are the ones created when the web reference was first added.

Answer (score 0):

Or is it something about GAC. If your class library assembly lies in GAC as an old version it won't be updated.